# Sencha touch Store always saves the already saved record, why?

Tags: extjs, touch

I have a store with autosync=true when I edit the record I see at firebug the PUT been sent to server and it's OK, but when I edit other record I see the PUT twice for previous record and the current one, and when I edit the 3d record the PUT been sent 3 times to the server and so on...

Any solution/explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think the response of your PUT request needs to include the data for the updated records, so that Ext JS/Sencha Touch can go through them and mark them as "committed", see Ext.data.Operation.processUpdate.